# Has Improved upon/ on or has been improved

Tags: passive-voice, verb-forms

Which sentence is right?

1. He has improved on his turn taking
2. He has been improved on his turn taking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the two options presented, 1) He has improved on his turn taking is more correct.

He has done the improving, the skill of turn taking has been improved, so he has improved on his turn taking.

"been improved upon" is generally used when the person who did the improving isn't stated. You might say:

> His turn taking has been improved upon

Although in the case of a person it's pretty clear who has to have done the improving, so it's not likely. A better example would be something like

> The engine's power output has been improved upon

It isn't stated, and you probably don't know, who actually did the work, but you do know that the engine is now more powerful than it used to be.